# Небольшой вопрос по Vue.js

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

У меня есть таблица:

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Логин</th>
                       <th scope="col">Действие</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Serega</td>
                        <td><a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"></a>
<button  class="btn btn-danger delete-event">Удалить пользователя</button></td>
</tr>
                     
                        <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>Andrey</td>

                        <td>
                            <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"></a>
<button  class="btn btn-danger delete-event">Удалить пользователя</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Нажимаем на *"удалить пользователя"* и мне нужно, чтобы получало текущий первый `td (id)` таблицы - через Vue.js нужно это сделать.
Знаю, это как-то делается через методы. Подскажите как?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Для того, чтобы была возможность манипуляциями данными необходимо эти самые данные задать в секции `data`.
Тогда появится возможность генерации таблицы с использованием цикла `for`.

Для сохранения `id` пользователя я отвел переменную `idDeleteUser` - в нее заносится `id` пользователя, поученный при нажатии на кнопку `Удалить` в таблице.

После открытия модального окна и нажатия кнопки `Удалить` уже в нем вызовется метод `deleteUser`, который получит запомненный `id` из переменной `idDeleteUser`, вычислит индекс в массиве и удалит вычисленную строку.

Итоговый код:

```js
  let App = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: () => ({
      users: [{ id: 1, Name: 'Serega' },
        { id: 2, Name: 'Andrey' },
        { id: 3, Name: 'Shenia' },],
        idDeleteUser: {},
    }),
    methods: {
      setDeleteUser(id) { this.idDeleteUser = id },
      deleteUser() {
        let index = this.users.reduce((result, user, index) => user.id == this.idDeleteUser ? index : result, null)
        this.users.splice(index, 1)
        $("#exampleModalLong").modal('hide')
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">id</th>
        <th scope="col">Логин</th>
        <th scope="col">Действие</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="user in users">
        <td v-text="user.id"></td>
        <td v-text="user.Name"></td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" @click="setDeleteUser(user.id)">Удалить</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Точно удалить?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteUser()">Удалить</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Документация. Данные и методы. https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B

Документация. Методы Vuejs: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html